# Gráficas de projectsend

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches, estoy montando una Intranet con la aplicación `projectsend`(http://intranetmineraguila.com.s116-195.furanet.com/) (usuario: prueba // contraseña: prueba33) El problema es que no encuentro el porque la carpeta my_files de cada usuario y las gráficas de subida de archivos no se muestran, el caso es que si que funciona para las cuentas de administración. ¿Alguien sabría decirme por que no se muestran las gráficas y por que cuando accedo a `my_files` los `CSS` no se cargan?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y un saludo.

Comment: Seguramente es un problema de las rutas, sin ver el código poco más te podemos decir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La carpeta my_files no existe por usuario, es simplemente un directorio que funciona como landing y dependiendo de los permisos del usuario muestra el listado de archivos para descargar.
Probablemente haya algún error en las rutas de los archivos, y por eso no está cargando el CSS. Fijate el código fuente de la página una vez que haya cargado, y buscá el link al archivo CSS. Intentá entrar directamente para ver si la ruta existe.

Por otro lado, puede ser que necesites activar la opción de rutas absolutas en la parte de opcioens de miniaturas, para ver las imágenes generadas.

Saludos!

Comment: Al final me he decantado por camiar el proyecto a nextcloud y ha sido mas fácil el implementar todo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por el aporte de todas formas.